# Handling Observables for Subcomponents

Tags: angular

I have created a component that I want to split into 3 subcomponents. Right now, my component subscribes to 4 different observables from a service. Once broken down, each subcomponent will still need the data from the same 4 observables.

How should this be handled? Making the same 4 subscriptions for each subcomponent results in more REST calls and adds a lot of redundancy. Can / should I keep the subscriptions in the parent component and pass the data to the 3 subcomponents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `@Input()` decorator and pass the values to your Subcomponents, but even you can do the `subscribe` in all of them  and you will receive the notification whenever the observable changes.